# My dimmer is not dimming. What should I do?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a dimmer. But once I connect the dimmer. The light always on. Even when I switch all the way the dimmer. When I disconnect the dimmer there is no light, and no power.

I need the dimmer for 4 lights. But it didn't works whatever I'm trying with 1/2/3 or 4 lights.

I see that it is support up to 900W. I'm sure the voltage is correct (220V).

One more info:
The room has before 2 switched for the light. I disconnected one of the switches, and there was 3 wires. I took 2 of them. I tried to connect them to the dimmer in both direction, and the lights always on. When removing the dimmer, there is no lights.

My question:
There is anything that I can do to fix the situtation? if not, how do I test the dimmer, and if you think the dimmer is not matching the lights, how to choose my next dimmer for those specific 4 lights?

Pictures:
<sup><sub>Click for full size</sub></sup>
This is the dimmer I bought:

[image]
[image]

This is the light I have:

[image] [image]

Comment: Unfortunately, my modern Hebrew isn't that good (no references to dimmer switches or 3-way lights in Tanach that I know of). Two things that you need to look for: "dimmer compatible" on the lights - incandescent bulbs are pretty much always dimmer compatible, but LED bulbs are not necessarily, and I can't tell what you have; "3-way switch" on the dimmer - a situation where you have 2 separate switches that both control a light is called, in the US, a 3-way switch, though it has other names elsewhere (and obviously something else in Hebrew).

Comment: You don't need Hebrew the important parts are English and digits (900W). You can see in the picutre it's not look like led. There is no match info about it:
https://www.niskoelec.com/items/1346954-%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%A4%D7%97%D7%9D-%D7%90%D7%92%D7%A1-60W-E27-%D7%AA%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%90%D7%95%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%94-SUN-LIGHT

If I translate it to English they called it "Coal Light"? but I don't see anything similar in amazon or outside of IL.

Comment: "and there was 3 wires. I took 2 of them" You took the wrong two. You are guessing dangerously! I can see to the right of your pic some standard EU wiring colours, but I have no clue what orange/brown is, although I could guess at it being switched live. What we need are details of the three colours you took out & what their terminals were labelled, then what the new terminals are labelled. You say you have 4 lights… how are you distunguishing between them to wire them up?

Comment: If the lights are truly 40W and not "40W equivalent" then they are incandescent. If so, then the problem isn't LED dimmer compatibility but rather the 3-way switch issue. 900W refers to the maximum capacity of the dimmer - that is rarely a problem.

Comment: More info. The green light on the dimmer is always off. I believe it really 40w. Maybe it's halogen?

Comment: Regarding wiring I tested all combinations of 2.

Comment: "I tested all combinations of 2" I cannot comment on the wisdom of doing that without swearing, really. I'm surprised you didn't blow a fuse, burn out the dimmer entirely, or electrocute yourself yet. We need colours & labels of old & new at minimum. You obviously have *absolutely* no idea what you're doing, so I'd stop right now & call a professional.

Comment: Have you identified the “hot” wire, some dimmers are polarity sensitive, making sure the hot is connected properly then a wire goes to the lights what is the other is it another branch that should be connected to the hot or is part of the lighting we don’t know. Note make sure to power down for the connections arcs can damage the controller and this type of control usually internally shorts or always on as the first part of failure.

Comment: Why are there green and yellow/green wires on switches that take 2 wires????? Those are for earthing only.  It sounds like this is *way, way* beyond your skill level, and your  "just try everything and hope to get the right combination" has burned out the equipment in question.  Also, experimenting will lead you to quit at the first combination that works, and many combinations will work *and then kill you*. Far better to learn what to do, then do the correct thing once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dimmer you got only works when it replaces the *single* switch that controls a set of lights.

You have two switches controlling a set of lights. To get that working, you either need a special dimmer that is designed to work in such a configuration or you need to rewire your circuit to make the lights controlled only by the dimmer.