# How do I connect my new dimmer?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a new dimmer for Led lights. I need to dim 4 leds of 5-watt each one.
The dimmer is for 220 V AC.

The problem is that I see 4 connectors in the back. But I have only 2 wires in my wall.
If am I understand things correctly I need to wire 2 new cables from the bulbs to the socket in the wall.
There is any alternative? Am I missing something?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do the instructions say about the four connections?

Comment: Very good question. No instructions

Comment: If I connect only the top L-IN and L-OUT. It's not dimming is always on.

Comment: You've bought a low-voltage dimmer. Input 240v, output 10v. You can't dim mains-voltage lights with that. What lights did you get? …and stop playing at guesswork, you'll blow up the dimmer or yourself if you're not careful.

Comment: Is this the next chapter of https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/241600/my-dimmer-is-not-dimming-what-should-i-do ? Did you finally blow that one up? Get a professional, before you kill yourself. The guesswork in comments under that was sufficient to know you have not the faintest idea what you're doing. You need to stop now before you do some proper damage.

Comment: I'm believe that if I do everything while the main power is off, and then while testing I'm only touching plastic - I'm out of danger.

Comment: & then you reassemble it all & go on your merry way, without realising you've wired a neutral to earth & now the screws in the switch are live… which you won't figure out until someone flies backwards across the room when they touch it. Please stop playing with people's lives.

Comment: Thanks! I will take care to not do it. If you have a link for safety instructions or a good book I will read. This is the do it yourself forum... By the way I really tried to take advices and consult local pros but no one knows about dinmers...

Comment: Dimmers wire up exactly the same way as the light switch you just removed. They even have exactly the same labelling - so long as you bought the right one. You photograph the old switch inc labels & existing wiring, take the photo to the DIY store & say "I need a dimmer to replace this". Then you move the wires from the old switch to the new, one terminal at a time so you don't mix anything up. Done. No-one dies. Anything more complicated & you hire an electrician.

Comment: Changing a dimmer is perfectly reasonable... *if it goes smoothly*.  The problem is, when it doesn't, you start "trying random stuff and hope to get lucky", when you should really stop and research.  And as we say, some connection combinations which "seem lucky" (e.g. involving earths) can set a deadly trap. But talking to us is definitely the right thing to do at that point, even if we can be salty at times :)

Comment: The simplest dimmer has 2 connectors and 20 pages of instructions.   If you buy one with 4 connectors, all labeled in unfamiliar ways and no instructions, it's just wrong to assume that you are going down the right path, and all you need is a bit of coaching from the internet and trial and error.  If you haven't developed the intuition to know when to stop and step back, I say this in a kind and constructive way, you should not be doing DIY at least not with electricity.

Comment: I'm not giving up (yet). and this is not the last chapter (@Tetsujin). The is the next chapter: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/242158/what-specifications-should-be-for-a-dimmer-for-those-bulbs
I don't believe that no one over the internet can't help me to dim my lights. I talked which every experts I know and it seems like dimming lights it thing of the past, no one no about it.

Comment: You must have talked to all the wrong "experts". Dimmable LEDs are a relatively new thing, but the DIY stores are heaving with new compatible dimmers, because everyone is now switching over to them. You can't move for them in my local big-box store. As already advised, they are directly compatible with existing switches & have identical labels on the terminals.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's ironic that you're telling people to be careful with things they don't understand, when you don't understand either. The "DC 0-10V" terminals are NOT outputs, and this is not a low-voltage lighting driver. They are control inputs for an external control to set the dimming level of the connected AC load. https://www.prolighting.com/blog/2020/03/25/understanding-0-10v-dimming-with-todays-led-commercial-fixtures/

Comment: @nobody - I wouldn't have bought that one in the first place, as I've no idea what it's for. What I do know is it's not the one I want. Evaluated & reasoned process of elimination can work just as well as foreknowledge. To be trying to figure out which terminal marked 10V to shove my 240v live is really a long way below that level of reasoning. Did you read the comments below https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/241600/my-dimmer-is-not-dimming-what-should-i-do btw?

Comment: @Tetsujin It's not relevant that *you* wouldn't have bought this item. The OP did, and you posting things about it that are flat-out wrong does not help anybody.

Comment: @nobody as is your berating me. Not helping the OP in the slightest. So far, that seems to be your entire contribution to this thread.

Comment: @nobody., Tetsujin. Thank you both for all the information! Both of are you are trying to helping. (And I don't have dimming lights yet, but this is another story)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You bought the wrong dimmer. This dimmer is meant for commercial lighting that uses separate dimming wires. It will not work with your regular bulbs that use only two wires.

Comment: I thought commercial stuff more commonly used 1-10v than 0-10v, but you're right it won't work either way...

Comment: @dandavis There are two standards, but both are called "0-10v" in marketing materials. Commercial stuff uses IEC 60929 Annex E, which says that 1 volt is the "minimum", but different manufacturers implement that in different ways in practice: some say that means 1 volt or less is off, and some say 0.3v-1v is the minimum available brightness while 0v-0.3v is off. The actual difference between the two standards is that commercial lighting uses "current sink control" and theater lighting uses "current source control."